# List control LVN_ENDSCROLL emulation for Comctl32.dll < 6.0

Tags: listview, winapi, mfc, comctl32

I want to use the [LVN_ENDSCROLL message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774816(v=vs.85).aspx) on a list control.

This message is only available on Comctl32.dll v6.0. which I cannot use for various reasons.

Is there any workaround available?

Actually I only need to get notified when the horizontal scrollbar has moved, I don't need the LPNMLVSCROLL parameter of the LNV_ENDSCROLL message.

Comment: Hmm, the first thing that comes to mind is subclassing the ListView control and trapping `WM_HSCROLL` messages. Raise your own notification and then delegate to the default implementation. Not a particularly elegant solution, but there are rather big differences between v5 and v6 of the common controls.

Comment: Sub-classing is the way to go.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Subclassing sounds good, I'll try this tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @CodyGray sSubclassing and intercepting WM_HSCROLL allowed me to make a workaround. Thanks.